# Maximum Subarray Algorithm

Tags: java

I'm plaaning to use the functions below to detect the maximum subarray of the given array, however, I need the start and end indices of the detected maximum subarray. How can I implement them so that they give me the start and the end of the detected maximum subarray?

Thank you.

```
int maxSubarraySum (int A[], int low, int high)
{
   if (low == high)
      return A[low]
  else
     {
      int mid = low + (high - low)/2
      int left_sum = maxSubarraySum (A, low, mid)
      int right_sum = maxSubarraySum (A, mid+1, high)
      int crossing_Sum = maxCrossingSum(A, low, mid, high)
 
      return max (left_sum, right_sum, crossing_Sum)
     }
}


int maxCrossingSum(int A[], int l, int mid, int r)
{
  int sum = 0
  int lsum = INT_MIN
  for(i = mid to l)
   {
      sum = sum + A[i]
      If (sum > lsum)
      lsum = sum
   }
  sum = 0
  int rsum = INT_MIN
  for(i = mid+1 to r)
   {
      sum = sum + A[i]
      If (sum > rsum)
      rsum = sum
   }
return (lsum + rsum)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before your return statement in maxSubarraySum(), check which one is the highest between left_sum, right_sum and crossing_Sum, and then check with a global variable that holds the current max obtained so far.
If the new max is higher, then save the new max and the start and end indices in another 2 global variables.
Not a clean solution, but does the job!